# Error "Incorrect Syntax Near '/'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I got a problem with my C#, whenever i try to save new data in the database coming from serial comm an error comes out and says

> Incorrect Syntax Near '/'

I tried every suggestion everyone gave but it just wont stop..Here it is the piece of code where it comes out.

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::test_new.Properties.Settings.Default.Database3ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO PowerData (Date/Time,Power(W)) values(" + this.powerTextBox.Text + ",'" + this.powerTextBox.Text + "'");

        SqlCommand exeSql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        cn.Open();
        exeSql.ExecuteNonQuery();

        this.powerDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.database3DataSet.PowerData);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Besides the issue with your column names, you should also look into using parameters to insert values into SQL code.  To learn why and how, check this out: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape special characters in table and column names like `/`

```
INSERT INTO PowerData ([Date/Time], Power(W)) values ...
```

In MySQL use backticks to escape, in MSSQL use brackets.

Comment: I already changed it but the error "Incorrect Syntax Near '/'. keeps on popping out.

Answer (score 2):

You've got some crazy column names there. If you want to include special characters in column names like that then you must wrap them in brackets in SQL, e.g. `[Date/Time]`.  A better idea would be to not use such characters in the first place.

Comment: Ok,already changed it..but error still pops out, the compiler says that it comes from this line..exeSql.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0):

syntax should be like below, escape all columns with special characters

```
INSERT INTO PowerData
([Date/Time], [Power(W)])
VALUES
(GETDATE(), 'test1')
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afcd4/1)**

Answer (score 0):

First, "this.powerTextBox.Text" - I am guessing this shouldn't be the same value for both variables

change your code to this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(this.powerTextBox.Text); 
string PowerW = this.powerTextBox.Text;
string sql = "INSERT INTO PowerData ([Date/Time],[Power(W)]) values(@val1, @val2);"

    SqlCommand exeSql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1",  dt);
exeSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2",  PowerW);
    cn.Open();
exeSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```